# How do you use having for multiple conditions?

Tags: sql, teradata, having

In the following codes, how do you exclude members's spending that's larger than $500 for each year (instead of total spending for all years)?

```
 select 

Year
,month
,memberkey
,sum(spending) as spending

from table1
group by 
1,2,3
```

Comment: Post your query, and we can probably help you out.

Answer (score 0):

A HAVING clause won't work here since you really want to aggregate at the `YEAR` level to determine which records should be included. Traditionally you would do this with a correlated subquery, but in Teradata you can make use of the `QUALIFY` clause:

```
SELECT "Year"
  ,"Month"
  ,MemberKey
  ,spending
from table1
QUALIFY sum(spending) OVER (PARTITION BY "Year", MemberID) < 500
```

Comment: I have updated my answer focusing specifically on the using `QUALIFY` as a solution.

Comment: I tried to add this line to my code, but it says selected non aggregate values must be part of the associated group. But my grouping was fine before adding this line. Do you know what the problem might be?

Comment: Perhaps toss your query in a subquery and then perform the QUALIFY outside of that. It's really a step that should act last on the results and that can get tricky with a GROUP BY in the middle.

Comment: create volatile table C
as(
Select
year
                                                                                                                                                                             
,age
,memberID  
                                    
, sum( spending) as spending                                                                                                     

FROM Table1

group by 1,2,3
QUALIFY sum(spending) OVER (PARTITION BY "year", memberID) < 5000
)
with data

Comment: This is what I have now.

Comment: Wrapping that up in a subquery would look like: `create volatile table C as( SELECT * FROM (Select "year" ,age ,memberID , sum( spending) as spending FROM Table1 group by 1,2,3) somealias QUALIFY sum(spending) OVER (PARTITION BY "year", memberID) < 5000 )`

Comment: It's working now, thank you. What does somealias mean? can't really find it googling. And is there a way to keep it at 5000, instead of completely throwing that row away?

Comment: That's just an alias for the derived table/subquery. You can use whatever you like for the alias.

Comment: I'm not following your last question "keep it at 5000 instead of completely throwing it away". Throw what away? Keep what at 5000? It's been a month, so perhaps I'm forgetting the context.

Comment: sorry i meant 500. The very last line of code - that's to completely remove any person who had more than $500 from the data, right? (instead of capping it at $500, e.g. assuming that person only costs $500 when he actually costs $100000)

Comment: Like allowing those records through but stop bringing through new rows when the total goes over 500? You could use some added functionality to the Window Function in play here in the qualify clause like: `QUALIFY sum(spending) OVER (PARTITION BY "Year", MemberID ORDER BY "month" ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) < 500;` which will be a running total of rows for this memberid/year combination month by month. It will stop new months from coming into the data for that combination when the total hits over 500.

Comment: So if we have John 600, Mary 300, Peter 200. After applying  that line of code, we would see Mary 300, Peter 200. But I'm wondering how to get John 500, Mary 300, Peter 200. Thanks